# How to add N OrderDict() in python

Tags: python, ordereddictionary, ordereddict

Assuming that I have 2 OrderedDict(), I can get the result of the (+) operation by doing the following action:

```
dict1 = OrderedDict([(52, 0),
         (53, 0),
         (1, 0),
         (2, 0),
         (3, 0),
         (4, 0),
         (5, 0),
         (6, 0),
         (7, 0),
         (8, 0),
         (9, 0),
         (10, 0),
         (11, 1)])

dict2 = OrderedDict([(52, 0),
         (53, 0),
         (1, 0),
         (2, 5),
         (3, 0),
         (4, 0),
         (5, 0),
         (6, 1),
         (7, 0),
         (8, 0),
         (9, 0),
         (10, 1),
         (11, 1)])

dict3 = OrderedDict((k, dict1[k] + dict2[k]) for k in dict1 if k in dict2)
print(dict3)
OrderedDict([(52, 0),
         (53, 0),
         (1, 0),
         (2, 5),
         (3, 0),
         (4, 0),
         (5, 0),
         (6, 1),
         (7, 0),
         (8, 0),
         (9, 0),
         (10, 1),
         (11, 2)])
```

My question is: how can I generalize the above action so I can get the (+) operation result for N OrderedDict()?

Comment: I suggest you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/15321776

Comment: checked it but still cannot implement it for this specific case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By testing each key for membership of each other dict you're essentially performing an operation of a set intersection, but you can't actually use set intersections because sets are unordered in Python.

You can work around this limitation by installing the [ordered-set](https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/) package, so that you can use the `OrderedSet.intersection` method to obtain common keys among the dicts ordered by keys in the first dict, which you can then iterate over to construct a new `OrderedDict` with each value being the sum of the values of the current key from all dicts:

```
from ordered_set import OrderedSet

dicts = [dict1, dict2]
common_keys = OrderedSet.intersection(*dicts)
print(OrderedDict((k, sum(d[k] for d in dicts)) for k in common_keys))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/FlawlessGrowlingAccounting

Answer (score 0):

Some naive approach using map-reduce. Note that I didn't test the following code, so it might need some adjustments

```
import operator

dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4]
dicts_keys = map(lambda d: set(d.keys()), dicts)
common_keys = set.intersection(*dicts_keys)
sum_dict = OrderedDict(
    (k, reduce(operator.add, map(lambda d: d[k], dicts)))
    for k in common_keys)
```

Comment: Sets are unordered in Python so by using set operations you would not get a predictably ordered result that iterating over an `OrderedDict` would.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to install an external package, a similar result can be achieved by using this function:

```
 def add_dicts(*args):
     items_list = list()
     for k in args[0]:
         if all([k in arg for arg in args[1:]]):
             value = 0
             for arg in args:
                     value += arg[k]
             items_list.append((k, value))
     return OrderedDict(items_list)
```

To call it:

```
dict3 = add_dicts(dict1, dict2)
dict4 = add_dicts(dict1, dict2, dict3)
```

If you want to call it with a list of dictionaries:

```
dict_list=[dict1, dict2]
dict5 = add_dicts(*dict_list)
```

More information about *args can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/15321776)